# Root squashing for NFS and SMB clarification

Tags: linux, bash, nfs, smb

Root squashing means that when I try to access a directory that has it enabled, I won't be able to use my root permissions because it will be remapped to a nfsnobody user or whatever user is specified.
I was wondering the following; if I'd create an executable on my own computer as root, and set the UID of (`chmod u+sx`) executable.sh and then copy that file to the NFS server, I still wouldn't be able to execute as root since it will be remapped to the nfsnobody user.
Nevertheless, imagine I'm able to connect with SSH to the same server as a normal user with average privilleges, no root or anything. If I'd execute that same executable.sh file there, it wouldn't be remapped, right? It'd be executed as the root user I'd assume.

Are my assumptions right, if not, some clarification would be really useful!

Another small question: when using SMB is there something like root squashing, since I can just copy a file from my own computer to an smb share (the file was created by root) with the UID set  (`chmod u+sx`) and execute it there?

Have an amazing day!

Comment: For the record SUID do not have effect on scripts.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, didn't know that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I'd create an executable on my own computer as root, and set the UID of (chmod u+sx) executable.sh and then copy that file to the NFS server, I still wouldn't be able to execute as root since it will be remapped to the nfsnobody user.

It sounds like you're assuming that "root_squash" applies to information reported by the server, but not to client identities. But it's actually the opposite: "root_squash" applies **only** to user credentials (i.e. who's performing operations), not to file ownership.

In other words, it means you cannot claim to *be* root when operating on NFS-shared files (and therefore cannot chown, etc), but it does not prevent *existing* files appearing as if they're owned by root.

This means that having "root_squash" enabled will stop your plan much earlier: it will prevent you from *copying that file* to the NFS server. If you perform the copy operation as local root, then the copied file will appear as if it's owned by "nfsnobody", as the NFS server will ignore your "I am uid 0" claim. If you try to 'chown' it back to root:root, the NFS server won't let you do that because only root can chown files, and your connection only has "nfsnobody" permissions.

On the other hand, "root_squash" will *not* prevent your local machine from executing files that are actually owned by root. That happens in the opposite direction: when you run a program out of an NFS share, it is still being read and executed on your client machine – not on the server – so unlike in the previous case, now it is the NFS *client* that believes in what information the server provides about a file's ownership or permissions, and "root_squash" doesn't alter those.

(So if /mnt/theserver/bin/su already exists and the NFS server says it is setuid-root, your NFS client machine will execute it as if it's setuid-root, regardless of root_squash. To avoid this, the NFS client would need to mount the share with the "nosuid" option.)

> Nevertheless, imagine I'm able to connect with SSH to the same server as a normal user with average privilleges, no root or anything. If I'd execute that same executable.sh file there, it wouldn't be remapped, right? It'd be executed as the root user I'd assume.

If you were actually able to create such an executable, then yes (but keeping in mind what Ninov said in comments: setuid only works on binary executables and is completely ignored for scripts).

But you won't be able to reach this stage, because "root_squash" would prevent you from creating a root-owned file in the first place.

> Another small question: when using SMB is there something like root squashing, since I can just copy a file from my own computer to an smb share (the file was created by root) with the UID set (chmod u+sx) and execute it there?

root_squash is irrelevant because SMB doesn't have UID-based authentication in the first place. SMB connections are purely account-oriented (i.e. clients must provide explicit credentials and cannot just claim to be "UID 123"), so there is no implicit root access that could or would need to be squashed.

So either the SMB share is mounted using a single account for everyone (making it as if *all* local users are squashed to that remote account), or the share is mounted in multiuser mode where every local user must supply their own credentials.

But as mentioned in the beginning, "root_squash" does not affect what the files look like; if something is already owned by root, it'll still look like it's owned by root. It is the "`nosuid`" option which prevents clients from accidentally executing a setuid binary, and it's a global VFS-layer option that works with SMB mounts as well as any other filesystem type.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I don't get a few things though. You seem to know a lot about this, would I be able to ask you a few questions on Discord since that would really ease the proces? If so my Discord is kenshie#3195

Comment: If not, I have two questions and can you also verify all what I'm saying is true? When I create a file with root as owner on my system and set the SUID bit and copy that file to the server, the root user will get changed to anonymous but the SUID bit stays.   When there is already a file on the server owned by root with SUID bit set and where I have exec permissions to, will the file still remap my UID to the anonymous user when executing the file or will it actually let me execute it as root (the file owner)?

Comment: Secondly , when I copy a file created by root with SUID to smb server, and I run the file in that share, it will execute as root right, nothing will get remapped?

Comment: Nothing is remapped when executing files, since that isn't an NFS operation – you aren't telling the server to execute the setuid program, so root_squash doesn't apply. (Again, the remapping is only done on the credentials you send to the server, *not* in the other direction.)

Comment: For SMB, because you must log in as a specific user, files you create via SMB will *always* be owned by that user, so you won't be able to create a root-owned file. (Stop thinking of UID sharing being the default and root_squash as a special case – everywhere else it works the opposite way; e.g. SMB doesn't tell the server about your local UID at all.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, then one more question because I still think it's not clear to me. I can copy a file owned by root with SUID bit set to the SMB share, though there is authentication system, that has nothing to do with the file permissions right?

Comment: It is definitely _somewhat_ related, as it controls what permissions (and/or ownership) you're allowed to _set_. But it really works the same way as local operations, or operations over SSH. For example, if you're authenticated as user A, then you cannot create files "owned by root" because you're user A, you're not root – and that works the same way between SSH, SMB, and NFS. (Keep in mind that **copying a file is exactly like creating a new file** – even if the original is owned by root, the "copy" will always be a brand new file and therefore will be owned by you.)

Comment: Oh, like that, thank you for the answer!